# Undestanding Hibernate Cache Usage Startegy

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have cache usage question, I have the following mapping. ST_CD is mapped twice to 2 different properties for whatever reason. Hibernate is throwing

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: my.package.State column: ST_CD (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
```

I have cache usage as "read-only", so i guess insert and updates are always false; why should I explicitly say insert="false" update="false"?

```
<class mutable="false" name="my.package.State" table="STATE_TABLE">
    <cache usage="read-only" />
    <id name="id" column="ST_ID" type="long" />
    <property name="code" type="string" column="ST_CD" />
    <property name="stateAbbreviationCode" type="string" column="ST_CD"/>
    <!- Other properites -->
</class>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create an Entity in hibernate, **it should be ready to use an a normal bean. Whether you cache or not it is not possible to update the database thru multiple properties**. So you need to use the ' insert="false" update="false"` on one of the properties.

Answer (score 0):

Its issue in the mapping,

the same column(ST_CD) is used in last two properties

```
<property name="code" type="string" column="ST_CD" />    
<property name="stateAbbreviationCode" type="string" column="ST_CD"/>
```

Correct Mapping would be something like,

```
<property name="code" type="string" column="ST_CD" />    
<property name="stateAbbreviationCode" type="string" column="ST_ABBR_CD"/>
```

Comment: Yes, as I said I had to map same column twice, for other reasons.